# Rails Middleware class not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleware, rack

I have created a little middleware app for tracking Mailgun events , in lib/middleware of a rails app, and 2 files, one for the Mailgun Tracking env details and one as a class MailLogger which has the middleware initialize and call methods. Code is below

mailgun_config.rb  (requires the class file)

```
    # frozen_string_literal: true
    
require 'logger'
require 'mailgun-ruby'
require 'mailgun/tracking'
require 'rack/contrib'
require_relative 'mailgun_tracking'

Mailgun::Tracking.configure do |config|
  #require MailLogger
  config.api_key = ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY']
  config.endpoint = ENV['MAILGUN_TRACKING_ENDPOINT']
  config.on 'bounced', MailLogger.new(@app, @logger)
end
run Mailgun::Tracking::MailLogger.run!
@app.call(env)
```

mailgun_tracking.rb  (middleware module class file)

```
  module Mailgun::Tracking
  class MailLogger
    def initialize(app, logger) # options = {})
      @app = app
      @logger = logger
    end

    def call(env)
      start = Time.now
      elapsed_time = Time.now - start
      request = Rack::Request.new(env)
      log_message(elapsed_time, request)
    end

    private

    def log_message(elapsed_time, request)
      payload = {
        response_time_secs: elapsed_time.round(2),
        path: request.path,
        ip: request.ip,
        body: request.body
      }
      @logger.info "Logging from Mailgun: #{payload}"
      @logger.info(payload)
    end
  end
end
```

and seems fine except the class MailLogger is undefined in the mailgun_config file. In application.rb have this:

config.middleware.use Mailgun::Tracking::Middleware
config.middleware.insert_after(Mailgun::Tracking::Middleware,Mailgun::Tracking::MailLogger, ENV.fetch('MAILGUN_API_KEY'), ENV.fetch('MAILGUN_TRACKING_ENDPOINT'))

Its required at top of file, so any tips  to fix welcome.  Thanks

Comment: It should be `Middleware::MailLogger` (or you can include the `Middleware` module - it will make its constants visible in the current scope too)

Comment: yes tried that, didnt work, I have altered the structure slightly and is still undefined. Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the error's stack trace to your question? It often explains the issue better than hundreds of words :) You've changed the code since my 1st comment, but your issue is the same - you expect constant to exist in the scope where it obviously doesn't.

Comment: Hi I fixed it all now by changing naming to:  module Mailgun::Tracking
 class MailLogger    and then created seperate Bounced and Delivered middleware classes to be used in main MailLogger module.   Middleware is now  use Mailgun::Tracking::MailLogger
use Bounced
use Delivered
use Mailgun::Tracking::Middleware